# How to get Registration ID from C2DM Servers?

Tags: android

I am very new to Android. I developed my project in android. Now I would like to add notification for my application. So I planned to use C2DM. I register to C2DM and i have received a mail. but i not yet receive registration ID from gmail. How can i receive from gmail registration. What i wil do? Any body pls help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you read this link http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest?

Comment: please be clear and specific with your question

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the Registration ID. It will not be emailed to you. The Registration ID represents One App on One Device, so each user of your app will have a separate Registration ID. The get it, you need to request one, and it is sent to you as a C2DM message.

This tutorial explains how the process works, and how to get the registration ID
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#example_manifest

Once you have the Registration ID, you need to store it on YOUR server, next to the user's record. Then, when your server sends a message to the user, it sends the Registration ID to the C2DM servers, along with a message. The Registration ID acts as a destination descriptor.